# how do you concatenate and keeping the list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

```
import numpy as np

array = ([a,b,c],[a,b,c])

array2 = ([1,2,3],[1,2,3])

concatenate_arrays = np. concatenate(array,array2)
```

# expected: [a,1,b,2,c,3]

# i want:[[[a,b,c][1,2,3]],[[a,b,c][1,2,3]]]

Comment: _expected_ and _I want_, aren't those similar terms ?

Comment: What is `a`? `b`, `c ` They look like variable names. You are also mixing lists and arrays.  Which do you want?

Comment: `np.concatenate([array[:, None], array2[:, None]], axis=1)` assuming array and array2 are actually arrays.

Comment: `np.stack((array,array2),axis=1)` is the simplest version of`concatenate` that will produce the `i want` line (with a string dtype).

Answer (score 0):

i guess what you're searching for is zip...

```
import numpy as np
array = (['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'])
array2 = ([1,2,3],[1,2,3])

np.array(list(zip(array, array2)))
```

...returns

```
array([[['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['1', '2', '3']],

       [['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['1', '2', '3']]])
```

Comment: Skip the `np.array`, and you can keep the mix of strings and numbers.